# Shortcut command for highlight column in emacs

Tags: emacs, highlight

There is not a single post about highlighting a square column in this community.

What are the command for that?

Comment: Hope this can help you: [a search on emacs SE for highlight column](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/search?q=highlight+column). Emacs SE has a greater Q&A base for Emacs' features.

Comment: What's a "square column"? The question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight the current Emacs column using any of the methods described and referenced on this Emacs-Wiki page: [Highlight Current Column](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightCurrentColumn). This includes using library [`col-highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/col-highlight.el) or [`vline.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/vline.el).

If you want to highlight one or more arbitrary columns (not just the current column), then try library [Column Marker](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColumnMarker). Commands `column-marker-1`, `column-marker-2`, and `column-marker-3` each highlight a given column (using different background colors, by default).